# Dimensionial Regularization (integrating over extra dimensions)

Tags: dimensional-regularization

I tried to replicate a result about dimensional regularizations in the review article of Howard Georgi, *Effective Field Theory* at: people.fas.harvard.edu/~hgeorgi/review.pdf.

On page 17, he writes about Integrals of the form:
$$I = \int \frac{d^4l}{(4\pi)^4}\frac{1}{(l^2 + A^2)^\alpha}$$
He then regularizes the integral in the form
$$I = \int \frac{d^{4 + \delta}l}{\mu^\delta(4\pi)^{4+\delta}}\frac{1}{(l_\delta^2 +l^2 + A^2)^\alpha}$$
and integrates seperately over the extra dimensions $\delta$ getting:
$$I = \int \frac{d^4l}{(4\pi)^4} \left(\int \frac{d^{\delta}l_\delta}{(4\pi\mu)^{\delta}}\frac{1}{(l_\delta^2 +l^2 + A^2)^\alpha}\right) = \\ \int\frac{d^4l}{(2\pi)^4}\left(\frac{1}{(l^2 + A^2)^\alpha}\frac{\Gamma(\alpha - {\delta\over 2})}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\left(\frac{l^2 + A^2}{4\pi\mu^2}\right)^{\delta\over 2}\right)$$

This seems to make perfect sense to me, but when I try to calculate the integral over the extra dimensions $\delta$, I run into problems. First of all, the angular part of the Integration over $\delta$ is $$\frac{\pi ^{\delta /2} \delta }{\Gamma \left(\frac{\delta }{2}\right)}$$
The radial part of the integral is:
$$\int \frac{d^{\delta}l_\delta}{(4\pi\mu)^{\delta}}\frac{l_\delta^{\delta-1}}{(l_\delta^2 +l^2 + A^2)^\alpha} = \frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{\delta }{2}\right) \Gamma \left(\alpha -\frac{\delta }{2}\right) \left(A^2+k^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2} (\delta -2 \alpha )}}{2 \Gamma
   (\alpha )}$$

Together I get: $$\frac{\pi ^{\delta /2} \delta  \Gamma \left(\alpha -\frac{\delta }{2}\right) \left(A^2+k^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2} (\delta -2 \alpha )}}{2 \Gamma (\alpha )}$$
All in all I get a extra factor of $\delta$ which makes the integral zero in the limit $\delta\rightarrow 0$. But it should not give zero? I can calculate dimensionally regulated integrals the usual way, integrating over all dimensions d at once, reproducing all the known results. But I fail at the Integration over the extra dimensions $\delta$.

Where is my error? (How) Is it possible to integrate over extra dimension $\delta$ seperately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The angular integration gives the **[volume of $S^{\delta-1}$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere)**, so there is a factor of 2 not a factor $\delta$ in the angular integration.  Explicitly:
\begin{align}
  \int_{\mathbb R^\delta} d^\delta\mathbf x \,f(|\mathbf x|) = \underbrace{\frac{2 \pi^{\delta/2}}{\Gamma(\delta/2)}}_{\mathrm{vol}(S^{\delta-1})}\int_0^\infty dr \,r^{\delta-1} f(r)
\end{align}